# Asking for clarification of “balancing socio-economic” and “non-governmental actors”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Kleiman, 2006](https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199548453.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199548453-e-031) mentioned that democratic governments would overcome the inefficient in producing optimal outcomes in public goods using **non-governmental actors** and market mechanisms under the guidance of government agencies.In contrast, in non-democratic governments, the legal and corporatist governance modes have been primarily employed for the policy-making processes.
By which, the overall aim is to promote law and orders in social relationships along with using major organized social actors for **balancing the socio-economic** development ([English & Skellern, 2005](https://www.inderscienceonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1504/IJPP.2005.009089)).

Can I ask two questions:

1> What does "**balancing the socio-economic development**" mean?

2>What does "**non-governmental actors**" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "actor" in this context is any person or organisation that does something.

A non-governmental actor is a person or organisation that is outside the government, so *not* actors like the police force or civil service. And this just says that governments will use non-government organisations to achieve their aims efficiently.  For example to produce food, the government will depend on private farmers (guided by various subsidy and incentive schemes) To build a new hospital, the government might hire a private architect and building contractor. The farmers, the architect and the builders are all non-governmental actor.

Socio-economic related to how the economy affects social change.  Socio-economic development is the joint development of the economy and society.  And balance development is development of all parts of the economy and society together.  Unbalanced development might mean one part of the develops too quickly, which other parts negatively.

Comment: Thanks @James K , can I ask any example for "**balancing socio-economic** "?